# What does /bin/bash $0 $0 do in the 5th line in the following case?

Tags: bash, shell

Can someone explain the penultimate line of the following code? I'm trying to understand what does /bin/bash command do in general.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ $1 ]
do 
  shift
  /bin/bash $0 $0
done
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to build a reverse-engineering of it to understand what it does by inserting `echo` before the statement:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while [ "$1" ]
do
  shift
  echo /bin/bash $0 $0
done
```

Running it as `./myscript a b c d e f g` produces:

```
/bin/bash ./myscript ./myscript
/bin/bash ./myscript ./myscript
/bin/bash ./myscript ./myscript
/bin/bash ./myscript ./myscript
/bin/bash ./myscript ./myscript
/bin/bash ./myscript ./myscript
/bin/bash ./myscript ./myscript
```

The `/bin/bash` just after the `echo` is printed as-is:
The next two `./myscript.sh` are the value of argument `$0` which always contains the caller command (here the `myscript` script).

So for each argument, this script runs itself with itself as argument, using bash.

> what does /bin/bash command do in general

`/bin/bash` is the bash shell interpreter with its full path on disk.

Reading the bash man page `man bash` should provide extensive answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

$0 normally returns the name of the script . $1 return parameter passed number one